# Adding a POJO into a Room database table

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, pojo

I have a POJO class `OfflineDataRequestInfo` which I want to insert into a database table as part of `OfflineData` which is my entity. but I get an error

How can I fix this please

`error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it. private final com.i6systems.offlineservicelibrary.offlineDatabase.OfflineDataRequestInfo requestInfoJsonX = null;`

this is my code

```
data class OfflineDataRequestInfo (
    val status: String,
    val userId: String,
    val fuelOrderId: String,
    val timeStamp: String,
    val fuelOrder: String
)



 @Entity
data class OfflineData (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "request_info_json") val requestInfoJson: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="request_code") val requestCode: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="request_info_jsonX") val requestInfoJsonX: OfflineDataRequestInfo
)
```

This is not I insert

```
suspend fun insertOfflineData(requestInfoJson: String, requestCode: String, offlineDataRequestInfo: OfflineDataRequestInfo): Long {
        var result: Long = 0
        result = OfflineDatabaseManager.getInstance(app.applicationContext).insertOfflineData(
            OfflineData(
                0,
                requestInfoJson,
                requestCode,
                offlineDataRequestInfo
            ))
        return result
    }

offlineHelper.insertOfflineData(
                    inPositionApiData.toString(),
                    "notifyInPosition",
                OfflineDataRequestInfo(
                    "in-position",
                    action.userId,
                    id,
                    action.timestamp.toString(),
                    fuelOrderData.toString()
                ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see you have 2 way to solve it :

1. Write a `TypeConverter` for your object `OfflineDataRequestInfo`
2. Add annotation `@Embedded`

```
@Embedded
@ColumnInfo(name="request_info_jsonX") 
val requestInfoJsonX: OfflineDataRequestInfo
```

Comment: tried that and I get
 A field can be annotated with only one of the following:ColumnInfo,Embedded,Relation

Comment: when I removed ColumnInfo and just used Embedded it worked fine

 Embedded
   val requestInfoJsonX: OfflineDataRequestInfo